# How to set fixed column width in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to set fixed column width in Apache POI.
I want to make my first column to fixed width.

I have tried with sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 1000);
            cellStyle.setWrapText(true); //Set wordwrap it is not reflecting

```
    public XSSFWorkbook generateReport(List<Dto> result, boolean isRes, boolean isRes1) {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    XSSFSheet sheet = null;
    XSSFRow row = null;
    XSSFCell cell = null;
    String[] headers = null;
    int rowNum = 0;
    int colNum = 0;
    CellStyle cellStyle = null;
    CellStyle headerStyle = null;
    XSSFFont font = null;
    CellStyle datecellStyle = null;
    /* set the weight of the font */



    try {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        headers = new String[] { ...values goes here...};
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
        font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

        headerStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        headerStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        headerStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        headerStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor((short) 200);
        headerStyle.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        headerStyle.setFont(font);

        cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        cellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);



        datecellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        datecellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
        datecellStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        datecellStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        datecellStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        datecellStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);



        /**
         * Writing Headers
         */
        for (String header : headers) {
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);
            cell.setCellValue(header);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
            ++colNum;
        }

        /**
         * Writing Other Rows
         */
        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        for (Dto detail : result) {
            ++rowNum;
            colNum = 0;
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);
            //sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 4000);
            cell.
            if(null != detail.getGid()){
                cell.setCellValue(detail.getGid());
            }else{
                cell.setCellValue("-");
            }
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            ++colNum;
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);
            if(null != detail.getName()){
                cell.setCellValue(detail.getName());
            }else{
                cell.setCellValue("-");
            }
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            ++colNum;
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);
            if(null != detail.getNGid()){
                cell.setCellValue(detail.getNGid());
            }else{
                cell.setCellValue("-");
            }
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            ++colNum;
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);
            if(null != detail.getName()){
                cell.setCellValue(detail.getName());
            }else{
                cell.setCellValue("-");
            }
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);




        }

        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
        sheet.createFreezePane(1, 1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return workbook;
}
```

Comment: So you don't want the width of column 0 to be formatted autosize? So simple exclude `i==0` from `sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);`.

Comment: It works ..thank you Alex

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[setColumnWidth(int, int)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int,%20int%29) should work ... is it because you reset the sizes to *auto* in your loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
}
```

Start your loop from 1 to headers.length instead.

Answer (score 46):

You can set the column width using `setColumnWidth` method of `XSSFWorkbook`. The 1st parameter is the column number (starts from zero) and the 2nd parameter is the width. We need to be little tricky here to set the width. To set the width as `25` we need to pass the parameter as `25 * 256`.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("MySheet");
sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 25 * 256);
```

Comment: For setting columns for all columns, you have to first get the number of columns into a variable and then loop the code inside the loop `sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 25 * 256);` where `3` will be the counter in your loop

Comment: To set the column width in one go, we can use `sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(<no_of_chars>);`

Comment: check this answer, it gives a more accurate x256 calculation.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818288/557968