# How to set cell width in two decimal points in Excel Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, width

Im trying to get the fixed cell width values with accuracy into two decimal points. But when the excel file is generated, the cell width is rounded into the whole number of the width size i want to achieve. Can this be done?

```
  private Sheet setupSheet(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {

    Sheet xssfSheet;
    xssfSheet = workbook.createSheet("report");
    xssfSheet.getPrintSetup().setLandscape(true);
    xssfSheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(HSSFPrintSetup.A4_PAPERSIZE);
    xssfSheet.setMargin(Sheet.HeaderMargin, 0.1);
    xssfSheet.setMargin(Sheet.BottomMargin, 0.1);
    xssfSheet.setMargin(Sheet.LeftMargin, 0.1);
    xssfSheet.setMargin(Sheet.RightMargin, 0.1);
    xssfSheet.setFitToPage(true);
    PrintSetup ps = xssfSheet.getPrintSetup();
    ps.setFitWidth((short) 1);
    ps.setFitHeight((short) 0);
    return xssfSheet;
}

Sheet sheet = setupSheet(workbook);

int widthExcel = 10;
int width256 = (int) Math.round((widthExcel * Units.EMU_PER_POINT + 5f) / Units.EMU_PER_POINT * 256f);
            sheet.setColumnWidth(0, (int) (width256 * 1.14));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(1, (int) (width256 * 0.49));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(2, (int) (width256 * 0.85));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(3, (int) (width256 * 1.45));

            sheet.setColumnWidth(4, (int) (width256 * 0.46));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(5, (int) (width256 * 2.85));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(6, (int) (width256 * 2.02));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(7, (int) (width256 * 0.66));

            sheet.setColumnWidth(8, (int) (width256 * 0.72));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(9, (int) (width256 * 0.86));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(10, (int) (width256 * 0.75));
            sheet.setColumnWidth(11, (int) (width256 * 0.90));
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not really clear. But if you want set the column width as `Excel` will show it in it's `GUI`, then this would must be done usig the formula given in [Sheet.setColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-).

`Excel` stores the column widths as integer values in unit 1/256th of a character width but shows them as how many characters fit into the cell as floating point number.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelColumnWidth {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet();

   float widthExcel = 10.71f;
   int width256 = (int)Math.floor((widthExcel * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH + 5) / Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH * 256);
   excelSheet.setColumnWidth(0, width256);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH is not available in the poi version i'm using. any workaround?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/constant-values.html#org.apache.poi.util.Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH

Comment: by the way why do we add 5 to `widthExcel * Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH` value here?

Comment: See [Sheet.setColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-): "...+ {5 pixel padding}...".

Comment: According to that "Please note, that the width set by this method includes 4 pixels of margin padding (two on each side), plus 1 pixel padding for the gridlines (Section 3.3.1.12 of the OOXML spec). This results is a slightly less value of visible characters than passed to this method (approx. 1/2 of a character)".
So if we remove the 5, can we get the actual value we pass?

Comment: `float widthExcelRecalculated = width256 / 256f - (5f / Units.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH);`. Of course only approximately, because of the rounding by `Math.floor` before.

Comment: This can only return 0 if `width256` is 0.

Comment: thank you for the width256 calculation logic.

Comment: public static final float DEFAULT_CHARACTER_WIDTH = 7.0017f;